# Why TIME_TRUNCATE_FRACTIONAL value of sql_mode parameter of MySQL is not available in AWS RDS instance setup using mysql 8 option?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I create a parameter group with **mysql8.0** then I cannot select time_truncate_fractional for sql_mode. But if I create a parameter group with **aurora-mysql8.0** then it allows me to set that value for sql_mode. There is no documentation around this on AWS. Can someone throw some light why this feature is not available? What other features of on prem mysql 8 community edition are not available in RDS instances which has mysql8.0 parameter group?

Comment: [sf] or [dba.se] seem like better places to ask about this server configuration setting, it's not really a programming problem.